# ZADD member with highest score

Tags: redis, addition, sortedset

Is it possible (or is there another idiomatic way) to ZADD a member with a score of the highest existing score plus one?

For example:

```
> FLUSHDB
> ZADD key 1 one
> ZADD key * mem
> ZSCORE key mem
1) "2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zrevrange` to get the largest score, and then call `zadd` to set the score to be `largest + 1`. There's no built-in way to do that. However, you can write a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to do the job:

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local field = ARGV[1]
local score = ARGV[2]

if score then
    -- client specifies a score, use it
    redis.call('zadd', key, score, field)
else
    -- get the largest score in the sorted set
    local largest = redis.call('zrevrange', key, 0, 0, 'withscores')
    score = largest[2]
    if score then
        -- update the score
        score = score + 1
    else
        -- the sorted set is empty, set a default score
        score = 0
    end
    redis.call('zadd', key, score, field)
end
```

Try it: `./src/redis-cli --eval t.lua key , field`